# Does "Armoring" an encrypted string always produce the same length output if plaintext was same length?

Tags: aes, gnupg

I plan on encrypting numerous plain text strings which all have the same initial length. I plan on encrypting with AES-128 bit key using GPG. I plan on "armoring" the output into alphanumeric characters. The plain text will likely be less than or equal to 128 bits (will be a fixed number once it's set)

My use case is very sensitive to the number of characters which are created, and having the encrypted data always be the same length (or knowing the upper bound) is required.

Is it expected that all of my outputs will be the same length? Is there some way to know the maximum length, or force the output to always be the same length?

Comment: Yes. "Armoring" is just base64 encoding, if the binary output has a fixed length, then the base64 output will have a fixed length.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just created a file with 128 `0`s, and then a second file with 127 `0`s and a single `1`, and used `gpg --armor --symmetric --cipher-algo AES foo.txt` and the outputs had a different number of characters in the encrypted portion.

Comment: A good reminder to always test assumptions, I wasn't aware gpg compressed by default. See Steffen's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII armoring produces the same length output for the same length input, where the input for ASCII armoring is the encrypted text. But, the encryption you do before the armoring does not necessarily produce the same length output for the same length input since symmetric encryption in GPG also involves compression.

Thus, the length of the encrypted data and thus the length of the armored data depends not only on the input length but also how good the input can be compressed. You can switch off compression with `--compression-level 0`.

But even if you have switched off compression the output length might be different of the input file name is different. Thus, you should read from stdin and write to stdout (i.e. use gpg as pipe) instead of specifying a file name as argument for encryption.